# node-telegram-bot-api | получение meduaGroup

Tags: node.js, node-telegram-bot-api

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы бот мог получить все фотографии с одного сообщения и прикрепить к своему сообщению.
С эвента можно достать только айдишник, а как из него получить InputMedia не понятно